# Could I forward a stream from my website to youtube through their API?

Tags: django, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm making a website for my church so we don't have to miss services and kids don't have to miss their classes during this pandemic and I made it so we can stream directly to the website but we can't stream to both the website and youtube at the same time since both require either an encoder or a webcam. Do you think I'd be able to somehow emulate an encoder to stream to youtube as well? I don't need help coding it, I just need to know if you think it's possible and if it is, if I should code a package so others can do the same. If I can help give other developers a bigger tool belt, I will. Through some modification of django-encode it may work. I don't think it's against their Terms of Service but I'll do more reading into that.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the camera data and encode and stream it to as many places as you like?

Comment: I thought I could but then I was informed that we use OBS and they would rather not just use a webcam. However, do you think I could use django-encode to kind of 're-encode' the stream to send to youtube?  It would take some testing as well as trial and error but it might work eh?